# Asynchronous Events Not Outputting to the Console

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I just created my first multithreaded program, and it is not working. The following is the **smallest complete program** I could come up with that portrays what I am trying to do.

Essentially, I created: a delegate that takes no arguments and returns a string; three methods (`FirstMessage`, `SecondMessage`, and `ThirdMessage`) that match the method signature of the aforementioned delegate; and an event of this delegate's type that contains the three methods.

Finally, I created a method `Start` that asynchronously runs each method in the event and displays their returned values. However, the program is outputting nothing. Am I misunderstanding something?

Here is the code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    delegate string Message();
    static event Message MyMessage;

    static string FirstMessage()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return "Message 1";
    }
    static string SecondMessage()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "Message 2";
    }
    static string ThirdMessage()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return "Message 3";
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        foreach (Message m1 in MyMessage.GetInvocationList())
        {
            Message m2 = m1;
            m1.BeginInvoke(delegate(IAsyncResult result)
            {
                string msg = m2.EndInvoke(result);
                Console.WriteLine("The message is " + msg + ".");
            }, null);
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MyMessage += FirstMessage;
        MyMessage += SecondMessage;
        MyMessage += ThirdMessage;

        Start();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One likely reason for this is that your program doesn't wait for the background tasks to complete before terminating.

You need to add some way for your `Main` method to wait for all background tasks to complete.

For the sake of troubleshooting, try just adding this after the call to Start:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

If that makes the messages appear, then this is the reason.

Exactly how to solve this, that I don't know, as the code in the question is too contrived to fix.